# Get version info of compiled/published dotnet application through bash

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I'm developing an ASP.Net Core project, where the **.csproj** file looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>dummyapp</AssemblyName>
        <Version>17.12.1</Version>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>centos.7-x64;win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When this app is published for *Windows*, I can get the version info from its properties. Which shows *17.12.1* as mentioned.

Alternatively I can run `wmic datafile where name="filepath/app.exe" get Version /value` and get the same version using command prompt.

---

But is there a standard way to get the same in linux distro?

I've looked into:

- [how-to-find-version-of-a-file-or-program](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-find-version-of-a-file-or-program-740020/)
- Experimented with this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306453/258615). Though it is for file-system!
- Tried `myapp --version` and `/fullpath/myapp --version` as mentioned in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440982/how-to-check-installed-program-version). Also tried solutions with the marked duplicates.

After all the trials, it seems, I need to implement something else in the `.csproj` file so as to get the version info using **bash**. Can someone point out what needs to be done, or give a hint about the same.

---

**`Main`** method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var root = new Root();
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                     .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                     .AddJsonFile(SettingsFilename, optional: false,
                                  reloadOnChange: true)
                     .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                     .Build();

    config.Bind(root);

    //some codes

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .UseUrls(root.AppUrl)
                    .UseConfiguration(config)
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseIISIntegration()
                    .ConfigureServices(s =>
                                     s.AddRouting().DetectTokenChange(config))
                    .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, "dummyapp")
                    .Configure(app => app.UseRouter(r => r.MapPost("dumptoqueue", 
                                      async (context) => 
                                      await Task.Run(() => AddtoQueue(context)))))
                    .Build();
     host.Run();
}
```

App built using the command line:

```
dotnet publish -c release -r centos.7-x64
```

Comment: Did you try to use [strings(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) ? It might be enough

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Looking at the linked doc, isn't `--version` part of `strings` as I've tried it earlier and also mentioned in the post. If you were pointing something else, can you explicitly point that out?

Comment: You should improve your question by perhaps showing the code of your `Main` (if it is coded in C#) and by explaining your build procedure. You need to understand more your [compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilation) process, and give it in your question. So please **edit your question** to improve it. Tell more about the compiler you are using on Linux, and explain how you build your executable from source code. What commands do you use for that build ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Updated my question as suggested

Comment: Notice that even in C# it is allowed to generate some C# source file from some external data in your build procedure.

Comment: It looks like your `Main`  is not using `args` ? Why?

Comment: I reformatted the code to make it less wide. Could you please improve the formatting, I am not familiar with C#

Comment: I did not pass any arguments because there was no need of any yet. It was  the default format format set by the dotnet template. I'm going through all the links you posted in your answer. kindly wait

Comment: If you want to (and I believe you should) handle `--version`  and `--help`  (or perhaps `/version`  and `/help` on Windows) you need to handle `args`

Comment: Yes I'm thinking about the same. In the meantime installing linux distro to work it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's assume your Linux program is compiled into `yourprog` [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) and that you are building it from its source code (so you can slightly change both the source code and the building procedure). It does not matter what is your build procedure, or in what programming language you are coding it. That `yourprog` file is probably some [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable or something else (e.g. a script) understandable by the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) system call. Use [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html), e.g. as `file yourprog`, to find out what its [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format). See also [binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) and read [about `#!` (shebang)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8968514/841108). Notice that *every* application program is started with some `execve` (generally done by your [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), but perhaps by something else, for example [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)).

You could use [strings(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) on that executable using `strings ./yourprog`; you'll then get most of the multibyte strings in it. Probably some of the (many) strings contain version information (if it has been put there at compile stage).

Regarding `--version`,  it should be a *convention* followed by your program. See [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065) answer. So *you* should improve your source code so that your program handle both `--version`  and `--help`  program arguments. There is no magic involved, you have to code that (perhaps your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) could generate some C# code containing version string; how that should be done is a different question, and depend upon the particular build utility that you use; with [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [`ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/) you'll just add some specific rules, e.g. in your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) or your `build.ninja`). So you need to understand and improve your build procedure. If you code in C#, you need to handle that from your [`Main`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/), so you need to improve your `Main`  to parse `args`  and handle appropriately `--help` and `--version` (on Windows, it could be something else). BTW, IMHO even on other OSes it is helpful to be able to pass some program argument to query the version and to get help (I don't know Windows, but perhaps it might be `/version` and `/help` instead of `--version` and `--help`).

Notice that [software versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) is *always* a human convention (even if using some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system, e.g. [git](http://git-scm.com/), is helpful). So getting that version cannot be "standard", even if it is very easy (it could also depend upon your project's conventions and coding habits, and perhaps your version control system). I guess that you could generate in your build some `_timestamp_version.cs` generated C# file and compile it appropriately and have that `_timestamp_version.cs` define some constant strings to be shown from your `Main`. In C with `make` that is a really [easy trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22411974/841108) and you just need to adapt it to your programming language and your build procedure (see also [this](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/blob/master/Makefile) `Makefile` and its `_timestamp.c` for a more elaborate thing related to `git`); in the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) it is very common to do that, and I am surprised that you are asking that!

Maybe there is some API to query some version metadata in C# (probably related to reflection), but that is a very different question. And you just should conventionally code to display some version related string with `--version`....

Remember that (even on Windows, and certainly on POSIX & Linux) [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) are practically not the same as [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s. An IDE -even on Windows- is just a [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) capable of running external programs (e.g. compilers, debuggers, build automation tools ...). You can (and you often should) run a compiler outside of an IDE, on the command line. So you can do basic [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) by generating some C# code (e.g. generating a file defining a few string constants related to version, etc). Read about the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) (which IMHO is somehow even used inside Microsoft).

Remember that `.csproj` files are not, IIRC, part of the [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)) specification (a technical report written in English). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9220290/841108).

Comment: Appreciate your effort into pointing out so many things in this answer. Will look into all the mentioned aspects, and yes my dotnet core application is compiled using `C#`. I'll get back and accept your answer if everything works out. As I'm making a cross-platform applicaition, linux is a new turf for me. So bear with me until I found the solution :)

Comment: C# applications are *not* native applications. A lot of ideas mentioned here - such as ELF objects (they are PE instead) - are just not applicable. The bit on metaprogramming makes even less sense, given that the version is already defined in the csproj file (which fills in the role of `Make`/`ninja` here).

Comment: IIRC, when I compile some C# code with mono, I don't have any `csproj` file. So these files are not part of the C# definitions.

Comment: The question is tagged as ".net core".. I think it should be safe to assume that the individual asking the question is using the default build system from .NET Core.

Answer (score 7):

It might just be easier to use `exiftool`, if all you need to do via bash is to find the version of a dll file.

```
$ exiftool Foo.dll | grep -i Version
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.55
Linker Version                  : 48.0
OS Version                      : 4.0
Image Version                   : 0.0
Subsystem Version               : 4.0
File Version Number             : 17.12.1.0
Product Version Number          : 17.12.1.0
File Version                    : 17.12.1.0
Product Version                 : 17.12.1
Assembly Version                : 17.12.1.0
```

Or even just:

```
$ exiftool -"ProductVersion" Foo.dll 
Product Version                 : 17.12.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `dummyapp.deps.json` that should be produced alongside your .exe. From this file you should be able to find the version of your app.

See (somewhat outdated probably) documentation for the deps.json-files: [runtime-configuration-file](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/Documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md)